# Renew command on mbox makes it freeze - Fix subscript size

Tags: math-mode, macros, lyx, fontsize, subscripts

I'm trying to change the font style of `\mbox`, but all my tries have failed. All commands I try either have no effect or make pdflatex recursively keep working and never finish and freeze.

This makes it freeze: 
`\renewcommand{\mbox}[1]{\text{#1}}`

This makes it freeze:
`\renewcommand{\mbox}[1]{\mbox{\tiny #1}}`

This doesn't change anything
`\providecommand{\mbox}[1]{\mbox{#1}}`

This doesn't change anything
`\providecommand{\mbox}[1]{\text{#1}}`

Why doing this? I'm using LyX, and it has a nice shortcut for \mbox (ctrl+m), and I used it for a long time for subscripts in a long document. Now I noticed that the font from \mbox is huge and must be made smaller. I discovered this earlier so some instances use already \text. So I either switch everything to \mbox, or everything to \text, or I find a new command. Though I would've prefered \mbox for the nice default keyboard shortcut.

My `pdflatex --version` is:

> pdfTeX 3.1415926-2.4-1.40.13 (TeX Live 2012/Debian)
>   kpathsea version 6.1.0
>   Copyright 2012 Peter Breitenlohner (eTeX)/Han The Thanh (pdfTeX).
>   There is NO warranty.  Redistribution of this software is
>   covered by the terms of both the pdfTeX copyright and
>   the Lesser GNU General Public License.
>   For more information about these matters, see the file
>   named COPYING and the pdfTeX source.
>   Primary author of pdfTeX: Peter Breitenlohner (eTeX)/Han The Thanh (pdfTeX).
>   Compiled with libpng 1.2.49; using libpng 1.2.49
>   Compiled with zlib 1.2.7; using zlib 1.2.7
>   Compiled with poppler version 0.18.4

Comment: Note that there are *many* other places where `\mbox` is used, so redefining it is surely an incorrect approach. You should not use `\mbox` in this way, and rather define your own command that you can use.

Comment: You can't define a macro in terms of itself.

Comment: You really really don't want to redefine `\mbox`

Comment: Thank you for your responses. How about redefining \text. is that OK?

Comment: @SamerAfach No, that's not good either. You *really* want to define a new command.

Comment: @SamerAfach If you explain a little more deeper what you are trying to achieve, then it would be easier to help.

Comment: @Manuel OK. I'm using LyX, and it has a nice shortcut for \mbox (ctrl+m), and I used it for a long time in a long document. Now I noticed that the font from \mbox is huge and must be made smaller. I discovered this earlier so some instances use already \text. So I either switch everything to \mbox, or everything to \text, or I find a new command. Though I would've prefered \mbox for the nice default keyboard shortcut.

Comment: \mbox does not change the font _at all_  `hello world` and `\mbox{hello world}` use the same font (just the latter will not line break) same is true of \text

Comment: @DavidCarlisle You're right. But I used it to get rid of the italian-ness of the subscript of some math where I need to write text in the subscript, like `$m_\mbox{external}$`, so it turns out that external has the same size of m, which is very ugly.

Comment: oh or are you in a math subscript like `$X_{\mbox{set}}$` in which case you should use `\mathrm`

Comment: See I guessed that just before you said (you should have said that in the initial question of course)

Comment: use \mathrm not \mbox and you will get correct subcript and subsubscript size

Comment: @DavidCarlisle -- if you happen to be in math mode and you use `\text` in a subscript, while it doesn't change the *font*, it does change the *size* (or, rather, *allows* the size to change), and that's what i think is being referred to.

Comment: @barbarabeeton yes we got there in the end (see last couple of comments:-)

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SE](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/questions/1436). Glad that you were able to get your problem resolved, but for future reference it would be helpful if you composed a fully compilable [MWE](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/questions/228) including `\documentclass` and the appropriate packages that reproduced the problem.

Comment: This is a typical example of how a “friendlier interface” makes easy things difficult. Translation: keep off LyX.

Comment: @egreg I disagree, my friend. LyX has made everything very simple and flattened the learning curve of latex. The efforts you would spend to start latex from scratch are way too much compare to the easiness provided by lyx. Anyway, it's a taste issue, so I don't believe anything I say would convince someone who's used to latex since they started :-)

Comment: You can help future users if you rewrite your question and its title to ask your real question -- how to get text right inside mathematics subscripts. Then one of the commenters can post an answer, or you can answer it yourself and thank the commenters there.

Comment: @EthanBolker OK! Will do!

Comment: @EthanBolker Please modify at will if you see it unsufficient.

Comment: @egreg This is a typical example of how a “friendlier interface” makes easy things difficult. Translation: keep off LaTeX.

Comment: @wipet: There is a *major* difference between LyX and LaTeX.

Answer (score 2):

Thanks to everyone contributed in the comments.

The answer I got is that it's wrong to modify `\mbox` or `\text`, and I should instead either create new commands with `\newcommand` or use `\mathrm` or `\mathsf`.

Comment: you might also consider making a new shortcut for lyx.  see [Defining shortcuts in LyX](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/53615/579).